# Diodes facing each other in a circuit

Tags: diodes

[image]

\$V_{i}\$ is AC source and the diodes are real.
From my search I found that if the diodes were ideal no current would flow which means that the output voltage would always be zero but since they are real how can I express the output voltage?
I have to find \$V_{o}=f(V_{i})\$

Comment: You have to think about the differences between ideal and real diodes to consider how this circuit will behave. Here's an example: real diodes have a breakdown voltage. For some voltages, this circuit will still conduct. Consider some other differences between real and ideal diodes and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Since one of them is reverse biased only saturation current can flow through it, furthermore it's a circuit in series which means only only one current can flows which is \$I_{s}\$. Can I find the voltage across one of them and from the I-V formula find something, which I'm not sure what?

Comment: Depends on what your ideal diode curve looks like

Comment: The curve isn't needed in here I guess and also it isn't given? I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: If the diodes are real then you need to know their real characteristics (conduction curves, capacitance, reverse leakage, breakdown voltages etc.). Also since the source is AC you need to include frequency in your analysis. Do these 'real' diodes have part numbers?

Comment: You can assume that they are silicon diodes or germanium ones, and for the input voltage \$V_{i}=10 sin(\omega t)\$ , nothing else can be given, not even these are given but I think there's no difference. But given these can the problem be solved?

Comment: You can use a "generic" curve with typical values. Develop an answer in terms of the names and symbols for varies points and regions rather than values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not told something about the diodes, then it's not possible to give a numeric answer, only a descriptive one. *For large input voltages, the output current is approximately plus or minus \$I_S\$, depending on input polarity, so the output voltage will be approximately +/-\$1000I_S\$ volts. For small input voltages the output drops and passes through zero when the input does*

If you are told the value for their saturation current \$I_S\$ and their *ideality factor n* (a frig factor often left at 1 for an ideal diode, but can be up to 2, or higher in some cases, to match observed behaviour), then you can use the Shockley equation, where the thermal voltage (26mV at room temperature) is \$V_T=\frac{kT}{q}\$, k is Boltzman constant, q is charge on one electron, T absolute temperature, \$V_D\$ the voltage across the diode

$$I=I_S(e^{\frac{V_D}{nV_T}}-1)$$

For large input voltages, this will still give you the descriptive result above, but it will allow you to fill in the detail of how the output voltage passes through zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you need to think about the diode capacitance.  That will allow current to flow at AC.